No puedo insertar valores en una base de datos MYSQL
El error que me sale es: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"
no puedo insertar ni usando http ni postman, el codigo del metodo para insertar es el siguiente:
async function createTweet(tweet) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const query = "INSERT INTO tweets (content, userId) VALUES (?, ?)";;
      connection.query(query, tweet, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve({ tweetId: res.insertId, ...tweet });
        }
      });
    });
  }


Y los parametros donde los pasas???

modifique el query por const query = "INSERT INTO tweets SET ?";, y paso los parámetros usando http de la siguiente forma: http POST localhost:3000/tweets content='Hola amigo' userId=1, ahora me da el error:  argument REQUEST_ITEM: "amigo'" is not a valid value

Como te explicaron en los comentarios, tienes que pasarle los parámetros... pero a la query.
Cuando haces:
const query = "INSERT INTO tweets (content, userId) VALUES (?, ?)";

Lo que estás haciendo, es poner marcadores de posicion los cuales serían los valores que quieres insertar en la query. Hasta este momento, no hay valores, solo hay marcadores que dicen algo va aqui.
Más abajo, viene el connection.query, y esta función recibe los parámetros (query, valores, callback) en ese orden.
Ahora, tu simplemente le estás pasando tweet, sin verificar nada. El parámetro entra desde arriba, y no hay verificación del mismo.
Entonces, para ti, que es tweet? es un array? es un object? es un json? al menos yo no lo se. Pero quien si lo sabe es:
console.log(typeof tweet); //Obtenemos el tipo

Entonces, primero verifica que cosa es tweet, y obten los valores correctos.
Por otro lado, lo que podríamos hacer, es extraer los valores del objeto.
//Este es tweet como objeto
const tweet = {
  content: "Este es un tweet",
  userId: 1
};

connection.query(
  "INSERT INTO tweets (content, userId) VALUES (?, ?)",
  [tweet.content, tweet.userId], // Extraer los valores de tweet en orden
  (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error al insertar el tweet:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Tweet insertado con ID:", results.insertId);
    }
  }
);


gracias por tu respuesta, no he podido encontrar la solución ni en foros ni en manuales, este es el metodo donde se obtiene tweet: async function createTweet(req, res) {   try {     const tweet = req.body;     console.log(tweet)     const result = await tweetsService.createTweet(tweet);     res.status(201).json(result);   } catch (error) {     res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });   } } 
